# iPhone SDK - Search Bar Thread Synchronization Question

Tags: iphone, search, multithreading

This is more of a high level "how do you solve this type of problem" type of question, as opposed to a "why doesn't my code compile" question.

I've got a search bar within an iPhone application that searches my data just fine.  However, i have the search triggered (handleSearchForTerm is called) after each keypress.  This creates some lag.

I like the idea of having search results appear automatically, but I don't like that for larger datasets, the act of searching appears to interrupt user input.

Is this something I can't fix aside from making my search routine faster?  Or, is there a better way to handle this?

One thought is that I'd like to be able to trigger a search only, say, 500ms after a keypress (unless there has been another keypress in the meantime, then reset).  Is that possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) to call the search routine after a delay of 500ms

**EDIT (after your comment):**

You can use [cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: selector: object:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:) to cancel subsequent calls to the search routine

Ofcourse, you will need some kind of mechanism to identify if a search routine is currently in process. Use semaphores for that.

Comment: If multiple performSelectors are called to do the same task (with different objects) does only the last fire? Or do I need to implement some kind of mechanism to get only the last request to be performed?